# Cypress cant mock image request

Tags: cypress

I am trying to mock cypress request for the image.

[image]

```
cy.route('GET', 'image/*', 'fixture:image.png').as('route')
cy.visit(podcastEditRoute())
cy.wait('@route')
```

But got

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms
>   for the 1st request to the route: 'route'. No request ever occurred.

Comment: Can i see podcastEditRoute()?

Comment: Did you call `cy.server()` before `cy.route()`?

Comment: Your route should use a wildcard `cy.route('GET', '**/image/*', ...)` if there is any prefix used in the calling app, e.g `xhr.open('GET', 'assets/image/test.png')`

Comment: `cy.route()` only handles XHR requests, meaning that a request of type `image/png` isn't supported. However, Cypress recently released an experimental feature and function, `cy.route2()`, which supports full network request stubbing. Read more about it [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route2.html#Comparison-to-cy-route).